# Example autonumbering in LyX

Tags: lyx, examples

Please take a look at this:

```
**1.1 Section 1.1**

 **1.1.1 Subsection 1.1.1**

 **1.2 Section 1.1**

 **1.2.1 Subsection 1.2.1**

 **Example 1.2.1**

 wqeadswqedsa

 **Example 1.2.2**

 sdaxzsad

 **1.2.2 Subsection 1.2.2**

 **Example (Section Number).(Example number): Example 1.2.1 continued**

 This example should be numbered Example 1.2.3; means the third example
 in section 1.2.
```

How do I achieve Example auto-numbering in LyX? and what paragraph environment should I choose for Examples heading?

I'm using LyX 2.0.3 in Ubuntu, book document class. Please note I'm very very new in LyX or LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a theorem-like environment, via two theorem-modules:

1. Go to Document --> Settings --> Modules, add *Theorems (Numbered by type)* and *Theorems (Numbered by type within section)*.

   [image]
2. To create an example, find *Example* in the drop-down menu in the top left:

   [image]

### Result

[image]

Comment: Umm I don't know how but Theorems (Numbered by type) and Theorems (Numbered by type within section) can't be added. The add button is greyed out https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75813759/LyX%3A%20Document%20Settings_001.png

Comment: @Nur Probably because you already have *Theorems (AMS)*, I guess they won't work together. Both seem to use `amsthm` though, so perhaps you can just replace the one you have with the two I mentioned, or use *Theorems (AMS, numbered by type)* with *Theorems (numbered by type within section)*. This will change the numbering scheme of all your theorems though.

Comment: by the way do you know about adding document class? if so please answer my other question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118986/how-to-add-unavailable-document-class-for-lyx-on-linux