# How to add unavailable document class for LyX on Linux?

Tags: packages, lyx, linux

I need the `IEEEtran` document class, and LyX asked for `IEEEtran.cls`. I have found it googling, now how do I install it?

I've found a similar questions but that's for LyX on Mac; but I'm on Ubuntu (not Mac) so I don't know if that question will help me.

Comment: As for LyX, after you install the package, remember to run Tools > Reconfigure. Other than that, this is not a LyX issue. Google "how to install LaTeX packages in Ubuntu". This will involve copying them to the right place, making sure the files have the right permissions, and running texhash

Comment: looks like I miss the tools - reconfigure part, thanks its working now, please write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for `LyX`, after you install the package, remember to run Tools > Reconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers` as [mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283813) and in Lyx, I had to go to the Tools menu and select `Reconfigure`. Then closed Lyx and reopened it.