# ! LaTeX Error: File `IEEEtran.cls' not found

Tags: ieeetran

I am new to the Latex environment. I am simply compiling the IEEE trans Latex format in Tex-maker but I am getting this problem. I have copied the ieeetran.cls file to the directory

```
tex>latex>ieeetran>ieeetran.cls
```

but still when I try to compile the project the error displays that ieeetran.cls not found.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `IEEEtran.cls' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

I have tried to install the package but it didn't installs.

Before voting down this question please keep in mind that I am new to the whole Latex and Tex-maker thing so please be polite while answering my question. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell what operating system you're using and what TeX distribution? And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Could you also specify the full path to the location where you installed `ieeetran.cls`?

Comment: @egreg I am using windows 10 and I am usning Texmaker 4.4.1. Thanks!

Comment: @cfr this is the location where I have installed ieeetran.cls "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\tex\latex\IEEE\IEEEtran"

Comment: You should better use the MiKTeX installer rather than doing things by hand.

Comment: @egreg I have tried the MiKTeX installer but the problem still exists. I have installed all the packages through installer but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Do you refresh file name data base (go to MikTeX Settings  and than click on Refresh FNDB and after then on Update Formats)?

Comment: You have to install it as `IEEEtran.cls`. Not the uppercase letters! Then go to the MikTeX update manager and refresh the file name database (FNDB). It is on the top of the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply download the folder in this link 
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran?lang=en;

Then, you have to copy the file IEEEtran to the folder where your working file are in.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 30):

If you are an Ubuntu, Debian or Linux Mint user try this:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers
```